# Why does Elaine insist on wearing the jacket?

Tags: seinfeld

In *Seinfeld*'s episode "The Outing", Jerry and George are reported as gay by a newspaper reporter.  (Not that there's anything wrong with that...)

Throughout the first half of the episode, Elaine is wearing a pea-green, fur-lined anorak.  Several times she refuses to take the jacket off when asked to.

**Is a reason given for why she insists on keeping the jacket on?**  It's also interesting (and I can't find a reason that) she is no longer wearing it for the 2nd half of the program.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### According to this fan-sourced transcript, the reason is unknown.

Checking this fan-sourced transcript for “[The Outing](https://www.seinfeldscripts.com/TheOuting.htm),” there seems to be no in-story explanation for Elaine refusing to take off her jacket. Look here; bold emphasis is mine:

> We fast forward a couple of hours and Jerry and Elaine are talking in the apartment. Elaine offers to talk to her and Jerry reveals that he has convinced her to "think about it" before she prints anything in the NYU paper. **And, for some unknown reason, Elaine refuses to take her jacket off**. Kramer enters, graceful as always.
>
> […]
>
> “Kramer convinces Jerry it's his birthday and, after **Elaine refuses to take her jacket off again**, Kramer presents the big guy with his present.”
>
> […]
>
> “Elaine can be seen mouthing the word “sh*t” and is, for some reason, not impressed with the gift. She picks up her purse to leave (**good thing she didn't take off that jacket**...):”

My guess is it’s just a quirky of saying: “Hey, Elaine has her weird proclivities thing!”

Comment: The whole show revolves around the four of them making life unnecessarily complicated for themselves.